# How to format data in when defining XML in groovy?

Tags: xml, groovy, markupbuilder, streamingmarkupbuilder

I'm quite new to Groovy and couldn't find  the right way to format/edit data in groovy when defining xml. I'd like to format my date to some custom format but I can't call any method from inside this closure, so the following fails :

```
def response = {
      mkp.pi(xml:"version='1.0' encoding ='UTF-8'")
      response () {
          status(0)
          count(data.size)
          objects() {
          data.each { row -> 
              object() {
                someId(row.myId)
                objectDate(callSomeMethodtoFormatTheDate(row.someDate))
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `objectDate( row.someDate.format('dd/MM/yyyy'))`?

Comment: Thanks, that does work !  
However, I'd really like to know how I can call a method (to add some more null check, logging, etc..)

Comment: In what way does your original code fail?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Call the method outside of the closure and return the data to a variable. Then use the variable to reference the data in the closure.

Example:

```
var = callSomeMethodtoFormatTheDate(row.someDate)

def response = {
    mkp.pi(xml:"version='1.0' encoding ='UTF-8'")
    response () {
        status(0)
        count(data.size)
        objects() {
        data.each { row -> 
            object() {
              someId(row.myId)
              objectDate(var)
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, but this doesnt work since "row" is only defined when looping through the data object and each value on each row is different..